# Mercurial: get information about repositories without cloning them

Tags: mercurial, repository

Few days ago I started experimenting with Mercurial, and everything went great, until I decided to try writting a small program, that gets the list of repositories and lists of changeset IDs for each repository from a remote server, allows the user to pick repository and changeset, clones it and updates to the chosen revision. This led to two questions:

1. Is there a way to get a list of repositories from server (besides parsing HTML)?
2. Is there a way to get information, such as tags, branches, etc. about one of the repositories, without actually cloning it first?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, Mercurial is designed so that you need a *local* repository for almost all commands. The only built-in command that will give you information about a remote repository is `hg id`:

```
$ hg id https://bitbucket.org/aragost/javahg/
3b2711b26dbd
```

To get hold of more information you can sometimes exploit the `raw` template for `hgweb`:

```
$ wget -q -O - 'https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/tags?style=raw' | head 
tip     a3a36bcf122e2ea4edbbe4ac44da59446cf0ee07
4.2.1   c850f0ed54c1d42f9aa079ad528f8127e5775217
4.2     bb96d4a497432722623ae60d9bc734a1e360179e
4.2-rc  616e788321cc4ae9975b7f0c54c849f36d82182b
4.1.3   77eaf9539499a1b8be259ffe7ada787d07857f80
4.1.2   ed5b25874d998ababb181a939dd37a16ea644435
4.1.1   25703b624d27e3917d978af56d6ad59331e0464a
4.1     e1526da1e6d84e03146151c9b6e6950fe9a83d7d
4.1-rc  a1dd2c0c479e0550040542e392e87bc91262517e
4.0.2   e69874dc1f4e142746ff3df91e678a09c6fc208c
```

That requires that the host is running the `hgweb` CGI script that comes with Mercurial. For a site like Bitbucket you would need to use [their API](https://api.bitbucket.org/).

Finally, if you can enable extensions on the remote repository, then it's possible to write an extension that exposes the information you want in a parsable format. I once wrote [such an extension](https://bitbucket.org/aragost/remoteinfo/) as a demo.

Comment: Just to make it clearer that it really doesn't work non-locally, something like `hg tip --repository https://bitbucket.org/aragost/javahg/` will fail; `abort: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/aragost/javahg/' is not local`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: yes, almost all commands will fail like that when you pass a remote repo to the `--repository` flag. It's only `hg id` and `hg outgoing` that will query remote repositories (in a quite limited fashion).

Comment: @MartinGeisler: `hg incoming` and `hg push` and `hg pull` also can operate on remote repositories I believe.