# How to list all mercurial repositories from a remote server

Tags: mercurial

How can I list all mercurial repositories from a remote server  in shell?

Basically I don't want to check out all the codes into my local machine. i just wanted to list all available repositories in a remote server.

Comment: Is this a folder on the local network or https/ssh?

Comment: @Nanhydrin i am looking for https/ssh.

Comment: What exactly is your setup then, hgweb? Or are you using a hosting service?

Comment: @Nanhydrin actually i have installed hg command line in a unix box. i have the hosting mercurial server url (mercurial.int.somthing.com/hg).  now i want to connect to the host url from command line and get the list of all repos.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this natively in Mercurial. Most of the commands only operate on individual local repositories. And I don't think there's any mercurial command to allow you to list repos from a remote server. If there's a page on the server that lists all the repositories there might be some standard command that will allow you to pull the page but then you'd have to parse it. Have a look at [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293085/mercurial-get-information-about-repositories-without-cloning-them)

Answer (score 0):

Login to the repo and do a ls command.
%ssh hg@hg.myservername

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).